# AWS Glue crawler only crawl the column name not the data

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, amazon-athena, glue-crawler

I have multi level json file which i have converted into CSV using Glue job. Now i am trying to use crawler on that CSV file, the crawler create the glue table properly (Shows status 1 created). But when i check this table in Athena it only shows the column names of table, it doesn't show any data. during crawler creation i have used classifier as comma, still its not working. Any idea, suggestion to work with this issue?
please find attached screenshot of CSV. also find the attached screenshot output in Athena.

input CSV: [image]

Output in Athena: only column name without data.
[image]

Comment: You may also consider updating the Glue data catalog directly in the Glue ETL job (without using crawler) - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/update-from-job.html

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution, i don't get the logic. Normally in crawler i used to select the file as source data, but this time i select folder name and it worked.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

We use the crawler to obtain the schema of your data and create a data catalog. With this data catalog, you can read your data with Job Glue or Athena...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).